# How do I clear the current line of stdout?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to make a status indicator in Rust that prints to stdout. In other languages, I've used a function that clears the current line of stdout while leaving the others untouched. I can't seem to find a Rust equivalent. Is there one? Here's a small example of what I'm looking for

```
for i in 0..1000 {
    stdio::print(format!("{}", i).as_slice));
    stdio::clear();
}
```

Comment: What platform are you on? And what is the corresponding function in other languages that you are thinking of?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On an ANSI terminal (almost everything except Command Prompt on Windows), `\r` will return the cursor to the start of the current line, allowing you to write something else on top of it (new content or whitespace to erase what you have already written).

```
print!("\r")
```

There is nothing available in the standard library to do this in a platform-neutral manner.

Answer (score 5):

Utilizing the ASCII code for backspace is one option, for example:

```
print!("12345");
print!("{}", (8u8 as char));
```

This will end up outputting "1234" after the 5 is removed as a result of printing the backspace character (ascii code 8). Strangely, Rust does not recognize \b as a valid character escape.

Comment: `\u{8}` gets you backspace. That Rust does not recognise `\b` as a valid escape is not strange at all; it is not one of the absolutely standard escapes, though it is common.