# How to clear the terminal screen in Rust after a new line is printed?

Tags: terminal, rust

I have printed some text using `println!` and now I need to clear the terminal and write the new text instead of the old. How can I clear all the current text from terminal?

I have tried this code, but it only clears the current line and `1` is still in the output.

```
fn main() {
    println!("1");
    print!("2");
    print!("\r");
}
```

The related [How do I clear the current line of stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823788/how-do-i-clear-the-current-line-of-stdout) does not sufficiently answer my question because I want to clear the whole terminal, not just the current line.

Answer (score 63):

You can send a control character to [clear the terminal screen](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Terminal_control/Clear_the_screen).

```
fn main() {
    print!("{}[2J", 27 as char);
}
```

Or to also [position the cursor at row `1`, column `1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4062051/214446):

```
print!("{esc}[2J{esc}[1;1H", esc = 27 as char);
```

Comment: A simpler way: `print!("\x1B[2J");`

Comment: @PavelStrakhov, that though wont position the cursor to the very top. But i'ts way much simpler if compared to the first.

Comment: @iamcastelli the second one is basically the same as the first one, just with `\x1b[1;1H` added to the end! The `\x1b[2J` clears the screen and `\x1b[1;1H` sets the cursor position to (1;1) :)

Comment: What operating systems / terminal environments does this work or not work in?

Answer (score 35):

```
print!("\x1B[2J\x1B[1;1H");
```

This will clear the screen and put the cursor at first row & first col of the screen.

Answer (score 12):

Solutions provided by the upvoted answers did not work the way I wanted to.
The `\x1B[2J\x1B[1;1H` sequency only scrolls down the terminal so it actually hides the content and does not clear it. As I wanted to run and infinite loop that re-renders the content shown to the user, this was problem since the scrollbar of my terminal window was shrinking with every "tick".

Inspired from [Clear a terminal screen for real](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367068/clear-a-terminal-screen-for-real) I am using

```rust
print!("{esc}c", esc = 27 as char);
```

which works great for me. There might be some drawback on other systems than I use (Ubuntu), I do not know that.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in the Linux or macOS terminal:

```
std::process::Command::new("clear").status().unwrap();
```

In Windows one:

```
std::process::Command::new("cls").status().unwrap();
```

This basically sends the "clear" command to terminal.

Comment: This doesn't actually have the desired effect.

Comment: this is working perfectly fine for me on mac and linux, not sure about the windows version

Answer (score 1):

See the precise answer at [cant-run-a-system-command-in-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65497187/cant-run-a-system-command-in-windows) given by [Vallentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2470818/vallentin):

```
use std::{
    error::Error,
    process::Command,
};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {

    clear_terminal_screen();
    println!("Hello World!");

    Ok(())
}
```

Such that:

```
pub fn clear_terminal_screen() {
    if cfg!(target_os = "windows") {
        Command::new("cmd")
            .args(["/c", "cls"])
            .spawn()
            .expect("cls command failed to start")
            .wait()
            .expect("failed to wait");
    } else {
        Command::new("clear")
            .spawn()
            .expect("clear command failed to start")
            .wait()
            .expect("failed to wait");
    };
}
```

See the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ff724e3f2bc5976352945ada4bfd7df3).

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

A better (in terms of cross terminal/platform compatibility) would be to use `crossterm` as follows:

```
use std::io::{stdout, Write};

use crossterm::{terminal::{ClearType, Clear}, QueueableCommand, cursor::{MoveTo, Hide}};

pub fn clear_screen() {
    let mut out = stdout();
    out.queue(Hide).unwrap();
    out.queue(Clear(ClearType::All)).unwrap();
    out.queue(MoveTo(0, 0)).unwrap();
    out.flush().unwrap();
}
```

Also, bare in mind that this will also hide your `cursor` in the terminal. If you do not want that to happen please ignore `out.queue(Hide).unwrap();`